# Does a bound sequence with close adjacent terms converge?

Tags: calculus, general-topology, convergence-divergence

Suppose $\{a_n\}$, $a_n\in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a bound sequence and $\Vert a_{n+1}-a_n\Vert_2\rightarrow 0$. Can we prove that $a_n$ is convergent?

Since $\{a_n\}$ is bound, we know that there are subsequences that are convergent. However, I cannot prove that they converge to a same point.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Perhaps that you meant$$0,1,\frac12,0,\frac13,\frac23,1,\frac34,\frac24,\frac14,0,\frac15,\frac25,\ldots$$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Eewps, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\renewcommand{to}{\longrightarrow}$No. Consider $n=1$ and this back-and-forth sequence  $$0\stackrel{+\frac12}\to \frac12\stackrel{+\frac12}\to 1\stackrel{-\frac14}\to\frac34\stackrel{-\frac14}\to \frac24\stackrel{-\frac14}\to \frac14\stackrel{-\frac14}\to0\stackrel{+\frac18}\to\frac18\stackrel{+\frac18}\to\frac28\stackrel{+\frac18}\to\frac38\stackrel{+\frac18}\to\frac48\stackrel{+\frac18}\to\cdots$$

This sequence accumulates on the whole interval $[0,1]$, but $\lvert a_m-a_{m-1}\rvert\in O(\alpha/m)$ for some constant $\alpha>0$ (say, $\alpha=100$ should work).